# Silly question of vector field

Tags: vector-fields

[image]

Updated:
For $\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}line, $ why is $\frac{\partial g(y,z)}{\partial y} = y + h(z)$ but not zero + h(z)?
(if it is$\frac{\partial }{\partial y} 1$...

Up-Updated:
I get it now, I just have some confusion of diffentiation concept...(lol)

$\frac{\partial g(y,z)}{\partial y} = 1$ but as i am finding g(y,z), i shall $\int \:1\:dy$ to find the y (g(y)part) then I just need to find the amount of h(z).

Comment: It's not. $\partial U/\partial y = 1$

Comment: It is that $g(y,z)$ is equal to $y+h(z)$, not$\frac{\partial U}{\partial y}$.

Comment: BTW $g(y,z)$ is the *integration constant* - it does not depend on $x$ - but may still depend on $y$ and $z$...

Comment: Oh i get it now! thx for the hints!!!XD

Comment: Yep, you have *differentiated* when you should've *integrated*.